# SolidWorks->urdf exporter strange behavior when click "Preview and Export..."

Tags: ros, sw-urdf-exporter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried to export a milling machine from a SolidWorks assembly to urdf using the exporter plug-in developed by Stephen Brawner. There were no problem when completing the form "Configure and Organize Links" but in the next step when I clicked the button "Preview and Export..." the exporter just stopped without any error message.

The assembly can be downloaded from [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3366143/urdf/MillingMachine.zip

Does anyone know about this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46764/solidworks-%3Eurdf-exporter-strange-behavior-when-click-%22preview-and-export...%22/) by [Peter Galambos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3465/peter-galambos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-10-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Many bugs have been addressed through newer updates of the software. Download the latest version and see if there your problem still exists. If so, please report it to the issue tracker: https://bitbucket.org/brawner/sw2urdf/issues/new

---

Originally posted by [brawner](https://answers.ros.org/users/2146/brawner/) with karma: 581 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdamSorrel](https://answers.ros.org/users/31651/adamsorrel/) on 2017-08-21**:
Unfortunately the same problem happened to me even with the newest version (as of August 2017). It's already been raised as an issue (see the link) on Bitbucket so I'm not adding a new one.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Despite being an old thread, this issue seems to be reappearing. I've spent quite a lot of time researching an answer, so I would like to leave a **solution/workaround** here. It should be noted that it's heavily based on Ari Kapusta's comment in the SW2URDF repository on Bitbucket.

In essence it seems that the automatic generation of joints fails without giving any warning or error. Luckily you can define the joints yourself and effectively skip this part of the process. You can refer to the original issue with a solution [here](https://bitbucket.org/brawner/sw2urdf/issues/20/solidworks-urdf-exporter-does-not-create) or for more detailed information check my [blog post where I've described the whole process in detail](https://programmaggotblog.wordpress.com/2017/08/21/sw2urdf-aka-solidworks-assembly-to-urfd-or-not/).

Hope this saves you the time and troubles.

---

Originally posted by [AdamSorrel](https://answers.ros.org/users/31651/adamsorrel/) with karma: 65 on 2017-08-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [markovalexey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27531/markovalexey/) on 2018-03-04**:
In your blog post your wrote `Check which joint origins and axis have been generated and whether some of them seem correct`. How can I check it?

**Comment by [AdamSorrel](https://answers.ros.org/users/31651/adamsorrel/) on 2018-03-08**:
After you have generated the joint origins, they will appear in the left widget where you have all the other objects. Sometimes they are generated in a wrong position, like the base of your robot or somewhere you don't want them. So you will need to move them to the right position in solidworks.

**Comment by [AdamSorrel](https://answers.ros.org/users/31651/adamsorrel/) on 2018-03-08**:
If you need more detailed description, leave me a message on the blog and I'll put up some pictures there as well.